# Layout support for Android foldable/flip phones

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, layout

My layout screen is vertically designed, how to give support if the phone gets flip horizontally?
My concern is how to give support to foldable screen mobiles?
For eg : samsung z or any other foldable phones.

Do we have any library or any code to support these mobile's app layout?

Comment: There's [developer guide for foldables](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/foldables) and you can create a foldable emulator to check if your activity folds without issues. Generally as long as you've properly implemented save state activity should be gracefully recreated under new configuration.

Comment: That's great. Thanks for sharing this knowledge.